# Powershell Replace text string

Tags: powershell

I have a line of text in a string that I need to replace part of it.

```
$OrgString = "BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB"
$OrgString -replace 'CONTACT:'
```

I need to remove `CONTACT:  MB` Keep in mind that the only thing that will be consistent in string will be `CONTACT:`. Everything else in the string will vary. Is there a way to do a `-replace 'CONTACT:'` plus a "number" of characters?

Comment: more examples of your expected output.  do you want all the trailing spaces/etc. `'BLUE ORIGIN             '` is different than `'BLUE ORIGIN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `-replace` operator is [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/) based, you should learn about RegEx

To match up to line end use `.*$`

```
$OrgString = "BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB"
$OrgString -replace 'CONTACT:.*$','#'
```

---

```
BLUE ORIGIN             #
```

If something else follows that should **NOT** be deleted,

```
$OrgString = "BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB  SOMETHING:  ELSE"
$OrgString -replace 'CONTACT:\s+\S+\s+'
```

---

```
BLUE ORIGIN             SOMETHING:  ELSE
```